# git push falla porque otro desarrollador subió cambios

Tags: git, git-push

Otro desarrollador subió sus cambios al repositorio remoto y cuando quiero hacer push me sale el siguiente error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'xxx@yyy'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Cómo puedo hacer para subir mis cambios?

Comment: relacionado https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24114676/1983854

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Resumen (asumiendo que estás en `master`):

Si no te importa crear un commit de merge, entonces esto alcanza:

```
git pull
git push
```

Si preferís evitar el commit de merge:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push
```

### Explicación

En [git](/questions/tagged/git), un commit es el estado de todo el repositorio en un momento dado. Además, cada desarrollador tiene una copia de todo y (si usan algo como [github](/questions/tagged/github)) existe un repositorio central. En este escenario, todos los desarrolladores hacen `git pull` y `git push` al repositorio central y ese es el único remoto. Entonces, imaginemos que inicialmente el estado de tu repositorio remoto es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que hiciste `git pull` sin problemas. Tu repositorio local tiene exactamente el mismo contenido que el repositorio remoto.

Vos estás trabajando feliz, pero Martín (otro desarrollador del equipo) hace `git push`... entonces el estado del repositorio remoto pasa a ser este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vos terminás de trabajar en el bug que estás arreglando y hacés `git commit`... en ese momento, en tu repositorio local tenés lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta ahí, todo perfecto... pero cuando hacés `git push`, falla con el mensaje de error de la pregunta. Esto pasa porque [git](/questions/tagged/git) no sabe qué hacer con el commit 4... supuestamente va después del commit 2, pero en el repositorio remoto, está el 3 después del 2.

#### La versión común

Una opción es hacer:

```
git pull
```

Esto lo que hace es traer los cambios del repositorio remoto a tu equipo e intentar hacer un merge. Si no hay conflictos, el estado final **en tu equipo** es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el próximo paso es subir tus cambios al remoto haciendo:

```
git push
```

y si el molesto de Martín no subió otro cambio, entonces va a funcionar sin problemas. Si falla por la misma razón, basta con repetir el procedimiento.

#### La versión de la brigada anti-merge

Somos varios los que vemos con malos ojos tener muchos commits de merge. Por qué? porque no agregan información. Por suerte, para los loquitos como yo, existe una forma de hacer casi lo mismo pero más prolijo.

Primero ejecutamos:

```
git fetch
```

`git fetch` trae los cambios del remoto pero **sin tocar las branches**... una vez que hacés `git fetch`, esto es lo que queda en tu repositorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto quiere decir que:

- `master` (la branch en la que trabajás normalmente) sigue apuntando a tu commit
- [git](/questions/tagged/git) sabe que el remoto (`origin/master`) apunta al commit 3
- si mirás el código en tu equipo, no vas a ver rastros del commit 3

entonces... el paso mágico es:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

cuando escribís eso, [git](/questions/tagged/git) se para en `origin/master` (el commit 3) y repite los cambios que se hicieron dentro del commit 4. **Si no hay conflictos** el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es importante destacar que ya no hay commit 4... tenemos un commit 5 que es "casi casi" como el 4, pero diferente (porque apunta al commit 3, tiene otro padre... y eso ya es suficiente para que sea otro).

si hay conflictos, vas a tener que corregirlos (la consola te dice bien qué archivos son los que hay que arreglar), agregarlos (usando `git add`) y finalmente seguir con el rebase (usando `git rebase --continue`).

Por último, es necesario subir los cambios al remoto (eso era lo que querías hacer desde el primer momento, no?). Para eso:

```
git push
```

Y listo!

Los conflictos existen y van a existir siempre (independientemente de que hagas un commit de merge o no). En lo personal, prefiero evitar los commits de merge a toda costa.

Y te dejo con una última imagen para que veas por qué puede estar bueno evitar commits de merge... sin commits de merge, la estructura de la branch queda mucho más clara:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Los gráficos fueron hechos con [draw.io](https://draw.io) y están disponibles [acá](https://github.com/g3rv4/draw/blob/master/Git.xml)

Comment: buf esto me vino genial! siempre me estoy peleando con git.

Comment: @lois6b si tenés alguna pregunta concreta, contame... me gustaría ir documentando de a poco conceptos avanzados de git mediante preguntas/respuestas incluyendo gráficos. Una vez que en funcionamiento interno de git queda claro, es sorprendentemente fácil

Comment: me ha servido mucho este post y sobretodo la buena explicación de @g3rv4